# How can I transform some columns into rows with other columns repeated?

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a some data that looks like this:

```
Count   Id          Test1    Test2       Test3
2417    118006353   0050167  0050380     0050390    
1445    118016614   0070015  0070105                        
1426    118013670   0050167  0050380     0050390                    
978     118005505   0050995  0098392     0099359                    
757     118002779   0050167  
735     118001930   0050380  0050390     0050771                    
694     118005514   0050380  0050390                        
683     117972784   0050557
636     118017677   0056009  0097709                        
601     118008066   0070015
```

I need to convert it to look like this:

```
Count   Id          Test
2417    118006353   0050167
2417    118006353   0050380
2417    118006353   0050390
1445    118016614   0070015
1445    118016614   0070105
1426    118013670   0050167
1426    118013670   0050380
1426    118013670   0050390
978     118005505   0050995
978     118005505   0098392
978     118005505   0099359
757     118002779   0050167
735     118001930   0050380
735     118001930   0050390
735     118001930   0050771
694     118005514   0050380
694     118005514   0050390
683     117972784   0050557
636     118017677   0056009
636     118017677   0097709
601     118008066   0070015
```

Is this something I can do in excel? (Or any other tool?)

Comment: What you are trying to do is called an "unpivot".  It can be done in both SQL and Excel.  Search for that keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really only have the three columns (or some other reasonable number), I'd make three different sets of data: `Count, ID, Test1`, `Count, ID, Test2` and `Count, ID, Test3` (to make these, just copy and paste your original data and then delete two of the columns). Now copy and paste each of these three sets below each other. Then use this formula in column D:

```
=if(C1="",0,1)
```

Then just filter and delete all the rows where the value in column D is 0. Sort as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a SQL Query, something like this:

```
SELECT count,ID,Test1 as 'TEST' FROM myTABLE UNION
SELECT count,ID,Test2 FROM myTABLE UNION
SELECT count,ID,Test3 FROM myTABLE
ORDER BY count,ID,TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this? A union should get you the results in SQL Server...

```
SELECT [COUNT], ID, TEST1
FROM TABLE
UNION 
SELECT [COUNT], ID, TEST2
FROM TABLE
WHERE TEST2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT [COUNT], ID, TEST3
FROM TABLE
WHERE TEST3 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function in SQL Server to get the result:

```
select [count], id, test
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  test
  for col in (test1, test2, test3)
) un;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5705a/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
UNPIVOT (Test FOR TestX IN (Test1,Test2,Test3)) p
```